# MVVM Implementation Query

Tags: c#, mvvm

Being novice to MVVM, I need to understand the MVVM and also need comments on few basic queries that I have.

I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in my test proj 
Ex: A Employee class, read data, display on form, edit data, on submit, update employee source using MVVM.

but need an idea as how can we make below code as a complete sln ?

1. To enable/disable button, how can I implement ICommand interface ?
2. What is controler in MVVM ?
3. From UI, How the flow goes to the model?
4. Interface INotifyPropertyChanged should be implemented on model or viewmodel ?
5. Why do we need ICommand interface and ObservableCollection in MVVM ?
6. Can we have MVVM for Windows or it is meant for WPF only ?
7. Why eveyone emphasizes on implemnting model first ?

Any good link that will explain basic usage of 
all the interfaces that we must implement in MVVM to say my MVVM implementation is complete ?

```
class EMP
{
    public EMP()
    {

    }

    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    public string EmpID { get; set; }

}


class EmpVModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public EmpVModel()
    {
        Employees = GetEmployeeList();
    }

    ObservableCollection<EMP> GetEmployeeList()
    {
        ObservableCollection<EMP> objEmp = new ObservableCollection<EMP>();
        objEmp.Add(new EMP { EmpName = "A", EmpID = "1" });
        return objEmp;

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public ObservableCollection<EMP> _Emp;

    public ObservableCollection<EMP> Employees
    {
        get { return _Emp; }
        set { _Emp = value; RaiseChange("Employees");  }
    }

    public void RaiseChange(string Employee)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Employee));
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You could start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Then move on to http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/advanced-mvvm/

Answer (score 0):

These are a lot of questions in one. Please have a look at [Wikipedia: MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVVM), and also look at the links referenced in that article for further reading.